# Переопределение стандартной ошибки класса PasswordChangeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть класс в джанге для смены пароля, он стандартный, название - **PasswordChangeView**, так вот, он возвращает строку **"The two password fields didn’t match."**, если новый пароль и повторной ввод нового пароля не совпадают.
Пробелема в том, что я хочу переопределить этот класс, т.е вместо этого сообщения(The two password fields didn’t match.) - вывести своё соообщение, но всё никак не могу разобраться как это сделать и в гугле толковый информации не нашёл.

Подскажите пожалуйста кто в курсе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно добавить собственную форму, в которой будут свои сообщения об ошибках
views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from .forms import MyPasswordChangeForm


class MyPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
   form_class = MyPasswordChangeForm
```

в данной форме есть константы для сообщений об ошибках, переопредели их под те, которые тебе нужны
forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class MyPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _('The two password fields didn’t match.'),
        'password_incorrect': _("Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again."),
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает :)